# Elementor dynamic text not responsive

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Hi I am using elementor pro and I am trying to create the archive and post template but the dynamic text is not repsonsive[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zduj8.png). I have disable all the experiments and plugins and enabled safe mode. I am using hello theme. I deleted the cache from the server and I am not using any caching plugin. Have anyone ever has this problem? Do you know any solution?

Comment: Because your single word is too long then you need to apply `overflow-wrap: break-word;` css on your element then it will wrap in line.

Comment: It is happening even if it is not one word. And it is happening only in dynamic texts.Not in a normal text editor.

Comment: You can inspect the tag and css and check if any other `overflow-wrap` is making conflict over there or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.